# how to query greatest ID of each value in a Sharepoint list?

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, wss

I want to query a Sharepoint 2007 list called `valueList` via web service and find the most recent version of each list item, so given this list:

```
ID | Value
----------
1  | 101
2  | 305
3  | 102
4  | 101
5  | 305
6  | 101
```

I want my query to return:

```
ID | Value
----------
3  | 102
5  | 305
6  | 101
```

In Access SQL, I would do this with:

```
select v1.* from valueList v1
inner join 
(select value, max(id) as maxID from valueList group by value) v2
on v1.id=v2.maxID
```

So far it seems like the only way I can do this in C#/CAML/Sharepoint web service is to run a CAML query to group my list items by `value` and order them by `ID`, dump the query to a DataTable, then go through every row of the DataTable, picking the last row for each `value`.  Code as follows:

```
//dataHandler constructor initializes Web Services Lists() object
dataHandler dh = new dataHandler();

string[] fields = { "ID", "value"};
string query =
           "<GroupBy collapse='true'>" +
              "<FieldRef Name='value' />" +
           "</GroupBy>" +
           "<OrderBy>" +
              "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
           "</OrderBy>";

DataTable listTable = dh.listToDataTable("valueList", fields, query);

//copy listTable structure to blank resultTable
DataTable resultTable = listTable.Clone();

//initialize value    
int value = (int)Convert.ToDouble(listTable.Rows[0][1]);

for (int ctr = 0; ctr < listTable.Rows.Count; ctr++)
{

    //check to see if we've gone onto a new 'value', if so get previous row
    if (value != (int)Convert.ToDouble(listTable.Rows[ctr][1]) )
    {
        resultTable.ImportRow(listTable.Rows[ctr - 1]);
        value = (int)Convert.ToDouble(listTable.Rows[ctr][1]);
    }

    //get the last row
    if (ctr == listTable.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        resultTable.ImportRow(listTable.Rows[ctr]);
    }

}
```

The `(int)Convert.ToDouble` is because the field is stored as a string in the DataTable, e.g. 1234 gets stored as "1234.0000".

This seems unnecessarily complicated; is there a more direct way to accomplish what I'm after?  I'm not required to use DataTables or CAML, if there's something easier.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a view in your Sharepoint list then get the datatable for the view?

Comment: @EmmieGabrielleLewis: From what I've read about creating a view, the most I can do is a group-by on the `value` field; I would still have to run a For loop through the datatable to get the highest ID for each value.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you thought about using linq?

Comment: @EmmieGabrielleLewis: I haven't used LINQ before, but it looks like a good solution for this problem.  Thanks for the suggestion--I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing your own versioning on the list? If you just used SharePoint versioning then it would be easy to get the latest version. :)

Anyways, CAML is pretty limited and in 2007 there are no joins ([in 2010 you have joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539975.aspx)). Unless you do some sort of pre-processing on the list.. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: This list is populated by a workflow: each time a certain event happens to an item in another list, a new entry gets added to this list, populating `value` with the ID number from the other list.  Because the event could happen to the same listItem more than once, the same `value` will show up several times and I need to record that an action has been taken on the most recently added copy of `value`.  Would versioning help for this?

Comment: So could you enable versioning on your "Value List" and update the corresponding list item? That way it is `1:1` instead of `1:*`. It would be recorded in the version history of the list item.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43684/how-to-query-greatest-id-of-each-value-in-a-sharepoint-list/43685#43685) is useful for me :)

```
DataTable dtList = list.Items.GetDataTable();
var grouped = from row in dtList.AsEnumerable()
          group row by row["Value"] into valueGroup
          select new { Value = valueGroup.Key, ID = valueGroup.Max(id => id["ID"]) };
```